# Javascript, defining two functions with the same name using prototype (across two different files)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, prototype

I have some code where there is a "var Signature" in one file (File A). And in the same File A a method is created "Signature.prototype.PreSaveSignature = ..".
And then in a second file (File B), the same method is created "Signature.prototype.PreSaveSignature = ..".

Now in IE8 and below it executes the method in File B ... while in IE9 it executes the method in File A. Howecome? Is there any valid reason for having two methods with same name using prototype?

Comment: It should always use the second definition, assuming both files are included and interpreted without errors. Have you checked the error console?

Comment: @techfoobar Ok I just debugged again and it is no longer doing what I said ... I was 100% sure but now I am not sure what to think :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two different methods on the same prototype with the same name.  The one that is defined last will be in operation for objects created in the future.  You can think of `Signature.prototype.PreSaveSignature` as a storage slot for a method pointer.  It can only hold one value and whichever value was last assigned to that storage slot is the one that will be used for signatures `Signature()` objects.

If you are getting different behavior in different browsers, that is either because you are getting different errors in one browser versus the other or you are getting different load and execution timing in the different browsers with something dynamically loaded.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, that's not my understanding. Changes to the prototype affect _all_ instances, including ones created before the prototype was changed: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4Em5m/ On the other hand pointing the prototype at another object with `Signature.prototype = { /*something*/ };` does seem to disconnect existing instances: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4Em5m/1/

Comment: @nnnnnn - you are right (http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YWDWq/).  I will remove that paragraph.

Comment: I think the "objects inherit their prototype at the time they are created" part is right, but because the prototype is an object its methods can be updated. But if you assign the prototype itself to point to a different object then new instances after that have a different prototype to existing instances as per http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4Em5m/1

Comment: @nnnnnn - makes sense.  I think your explanation is where I got the notion of objects inherit their prototype at creation time, but I didn't fully think it through as you've explained.